# Setting the backgroundImage of an div to a gif during runtime

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, gif

I have an asset folder full of GIFs. During runtime, I want to use one of the GIFs as the backgroundImage of a div. I tried the following method.

```
.weather{
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 10px -2px 20px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 30%);
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
    background-image: none;
}
```

```
function getCurrentWeatherGIF (description) {

    let gifInfo = []
    let gif
    let fontColor

    switch(description){
        case "clear sky":
            gif = "url(../../assets/gifs/sunny.gif)"
            fontColor = "#000"
            break

        case "light rain":
        case "moderate rain":
            gif = "url(../../assets/gifs/rain.gif)"
            fontColor = "#fff"
            break

        case "few clouds":
        case "overcast clouds":
        case "scattered clouds":
            gif = "url(../../assets/gifs/cloudy.gif)"
            fontColor = "#000"
            break

        default:
            gif = "url(../../assets/gifs/unknown.gif)"
            fontColor = "#000"
            break
        }

        gifInfo = [gif, fontColor]
        return gifInfo
    };

<div className = "weather" onLoad = {() => {
                let gifInfo = getCurrentWeatherGIF(data.weather[0].description)
                document.getElementsByClassName("weather")[0].style.backgroundImage = gifInfo[0]
                document.getElementsByClassName("weather")[0].style.color = gifInfo[1]
        }}>
</div>
```

The GIF is not loaded as weather's backgroundImage, instead I get a white background.

[image]

However, if I hard code the GIF's url inside my style sheet, I get the GIF background.

[image]

How should I go about changing my div's backgroundImage with a GIF when I load the page?

UPDATE: changed the sunny variable to gifInfo[0]. Thanks for pointing out my mistake.

UPDATE 2: uploaded an console image. I don't see any 404s.

UPDATE 3: Added CSS, just in case someone wants to point out a better approach with using the CSS instead of pure JS.

[image]

Comment: What does `data.weather[0].description` contains and what `gifInfo` value is?

Comment: Check dev tools and see if the URL is getting set truly.

Comment: And you don't use actual returned value in `.style.backgroundImage = sunny` and I don't see where `sunny` is defined, so it may be `undefined`

Comment: @Justinas `data.weather[0].description` returns a string that goes into the switch statement, which returns the GIF url and the text color. Also, the `sunny` variable is a mistake on my part. Changed it to correct variable.

Comment: _"However, if I hard code the GIF's url inside my style sheet, I get the GIF background."_ - most likely a path problem then, you should see a 404 for the image URL in your dev tools, I suppose? Relative URLs in stylesheets, are relative _to_ the stylesheet URL. If you are setting inline styles though (which is what your JS is doing), they will be treated as relative to the path of your HTML document that this happens in.

Comment: That being said - why do this via inline styles in the first place? Both the background image and the color should rather be set by rules in your stylesheet - and then all you do is set the corresponding _class_ on the element, to apply one of those rules. And if you name your classes corresponding to your descriptions - say, `.clear-sky` for `clear sky`, then you won't even need the switch any more, all you had to do was replace spaces in your description with hyphens, and then assign that as class to the element ...